# child iframe to call parent iframe, but only when it is done loading using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a webpage default.html that has 3 iframes in it.

The 2nd iframe makes a call the parent like this:

```
var someHtml = "...";
parent.setSomeHtml(someHtml);
```

In default.html, the setSomeHtml function simply sets the html from the child iframe like:

```
$("#a").html(someHtml);
```

So this works, but sometimes it doesn't and I suspect it is a timing issue.

Default.html has jquery loaded, how can I make sure that my calls only happen after all the iframes (and parent) have been loaded i.e $(document).ready

Is this possible?

Comment: why don't you call `parent.setSomeHtml(someHtml)` in the ready function of the ajax?

Comment: the child iframe doesn't have jquery loaded.